# List the filenames of attachments

Tags: vba, outlook, filenames, attachment

In this exam I get the number of "attachment file"  for an email in draft data.

Is there any way to get the name of this file in a msgbox or combobox or anything?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim a As Attachments
Dim myitem As Folder
Dim myitem1 As MailItem

Set myitem = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To myitem.Items.Count

If myitem.Items(i) = test1 Then

Set myitem1 = myitem.Items(i)

Set a = myitem1.Attachments

MsgBox a.Count

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim a As Attachments
Dim myitem As Folder
Dim myitem1 As MailItem
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set myitem = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

For i = 1 To myitem.Items.Count
  If myitem.Items(i) = test1 Then
    Set myitem1 = myitem.Items(i)
    Set a = myitem1.Attachments

    MsgBox a.Count

    ' added this code
    For j = 1 To myitem1.Attachments.Count
      MsgBox myitem1.Attachments.Item(i).DisplayName ' or .Filename
    Next j

  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the difference between `.DisplayName` and `.FileName`?

Comment: @SysDragon DisplayName `Returns or sets a String representing the name, which does not need to be the actual file name, displayed below the icon representing the embedded attachment.` Filename `Returns a String representing the file name of the attachment.`